# Set up environment varialbe during deployment for Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances

I am deploying my machine learning model to an azure container instance through a pipeline using the code snipplet below:

```
from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice

deployment_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(
    cpu_cores=0.5, memory_gb=1, auth_enabled=True
)
```

And the problem is that I have a secret environment which i want to use in `score.py` but since I cannot pass this value or cannot set an environment variable, i am unable to use it.

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? Setup the variable during the container creation :

```
az container create `
  --resource-group <resource group>`
  --name <name> `
  --image <image> `
  --os-type <os type> `
  --environment-variables public_1="public_2" `
  --secure-environment-variables secret_1="secret_1"
```

From the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/containerinstance?view=azure-python)

```
container = Container(name=container_group_name,
                          image=container_image_name,
                          resources=container_resource_requirements,
                          command=start_command_line.split(),
                          environment_variables=[env_var_1, env_var_2])
```

Comment: Actually does not because I am creating an instanse through Python SDK and it is creating the container automatically.

Comment: You could switch to the technique above and run via azure CLI.

Comment: Switching to this configuration is going to make things difficult for me because I already set up everything in the Python SDK configuration. If is there any way with the current method i am using i would be very grateful

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/containerinstance?view=azure-python - Part way down in this document it mentions environment vars.

```
container = Container(name=container_group_name,
                          image=container_image_name,
                          resources=container_resource_requirements,
                          command=start_command_line.split(),
                          environment_variables=[env_var_1, env_var_2])
```